# How to do actions based on numbers

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to make a shop in my game.  I have a label that updates dynamically for the

amount of money the player has.  My issue is that I need to figure out some type of if

statement so if the player has enough money, do x.  If not, do y.  My label with the money is

cash Amount.  If someone could help me write an if statement with lines for if the player has

enough money and if they don't, I would be very thankful.  Thanks so much!

Comment: -1 = Nobody knows what your code looks like, and you apparently haven't actually tried anything yet.

Comment: So since you already know it should be an if statement, what beyond that are you stuck on?

Comment: Why are you basing your calculation off of the label? You should be keeping the amount of money in a proper numeric variable. The label should only be used to display the number in a nice format.

Comment: You really need to ask a question with actual code and show what you have tried. Asking a general design question is not appropriate to say it is iPhone or Objective-C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let we say X = 250
players money = Y

```
if (Y>=X) {
       //then your player have enough money
       //do your x here
    } else {
        //then your player does not have enough money
        //do your y here
    }
```

Comment: @user1542348 your welcome. if this answer is helped you then accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the problem that you are having is that you don't know how to determine what the amount in the label is.

If so, all you have to do is convert it into an integer as so:

```
int val = [cashAmount.text intValue];
```

and then use that `val` to determine whether or not the player has enough.

Comment: he want if statement logic.

Comment: And data should not be stored in a view.